# Git 'Detached Head'

Tags: git, github

I met with some troubles when using github to get some source codes. My goal is to install ndn-cxx-0.5.1.

1. Firstly, I used `sudo git clone https://github.com/named-data/ndn-cxx` to download the files. (The system said that I had not installed `git`, so I used `sudo apt-get install git` to install it.) The results were as follows:

   ```
   zhao@ubuntu:sudo apt-get install git
   zhao@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib$ sudo git clone https://github.com/named-data/ndn-cxx
   Cloning into 'ndn-cxx'...
   remote: Counting objects: 24174, done.
   remote: Total 24174 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 24174
   Receiving objects: 100% (24174/24174), 11.04 MiB | 29.00 KiB/s, done.
   Resolving deltas: 100% (17441/17441), done.
   Checking connectivity... done.
   ```
2. Secondly, I turn to the root of the file: `cd /usr/local/lib/ndn-cxx`,a part of the  results showed as follows:

   ```
   zhao@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/ndn-cxx$ git tag
   ndn-cxx-0.4.1
   ndn-cxx-0.5.0
   ndn-cxx-0.5.1
   ndn-cxx-0.6.0
   ```
3. Thirdly, I used `sudo git checkout ndn-cxx-0.5.1` to try to install the v0.5.1, but *the problems appeared:*

   ```
   zhao@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/ndn-cxx$ sudo git checkout ndn-cxx-0.5.1
   Note: checking out 'ndn-cxx-0.5.1'.

   You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
   changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
   state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

   If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
   do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

   git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

   HEAD is now at aa8b378... docs: Prepare release 0.5.1
   ```

I used to successfully install it using the same steps, but problems appeared when I try to install a new one now.

Can you help me solve the problems? How can I avoid such problems?

Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/detached-head-when-checkout-commit

Answer (score 3):

Detached head state is what you are in after you have checked out some commit that is not the head (most recent commit) of any particular branch, it's just some commit state from at some point in the project's history.

In this case you checked out a commit that was tagged.  If you specifically wanted to see the project as it stood at the time it was tagged, then you have succeeded.  You can then make and install the software as you like.

Check to see if the project has a 0.5 *branch* in case they're still maintaining that version and you want to get new changes that have since been made to that branch.  But if you're specifically picking that tagged commit because you don't want any of the changes since then, then you have what you wanted.

Detached head state is of relevance if you want to actually make any changes yourself.  Since you are not at the head of any particular branch, changes you make won't advance any branch, so they are of relevance only to you who holds the commit ID.  You could create a new branch based on your current head, and then you can push that branch and share it with people.  But then all you're doing is applying changes to some random old commit, and this new branch won't incorporate any changes that have already been made to the project since that random commit.  What you probably want to do instead is check out a current branch and apply the changes to that instead.

As long as you just want to read or compile that old commit without making any changes to the project that you want others to receive, it's not a problem.